How to style a nested Tabulator table (that is nested in a cell) similar to the parent row?
I display a nested Tabulator table inside a cell.
Here is all the code you need to replicate:
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@6.2.0/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>   
<div id="example-table"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@6.2.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.4.4/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //define some sample data, with the sub-table data held in the subtable parameter
    var tableData = [
        {id:1, parent:"Bob", children:[{child:"Craig", age:18}]},
        {id:2, parent:"Ann", children:[{child:"Bella", age:14}, {child:"Shaun", age:11}]},
        {id:3, parent:"Jim", children:[{child:"David", age:15}, {child:"Alice", age:17}]},
    ];

    let table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:200,
        data:tableData,
        layout:"fitDataFill",
        columns:[
            {title:"Id", field:"id"},
            {title:"Parent", field:"parent"},
            {title:"Children", field:"children",
                formatter:function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
                    //create and style holder elements
                    let holderEl = document.createElement("div");
                    let tableEl = document.createElement("div");
                    holderEl.appendChild(tableEl);

                    let subTable = new Tabulator(tableEl, {
                        layout:"fitDataStretch",
                        headerVisible:false,
                        data:cell.getValue(),
                        columns:[
                            {title:"Child", field:"child"},
                            {title:"Age", field:"age"}
                        ]
                    })
                    cell.getRow().normalizeHeight();
                    return holderEl;
                },
            },
        ],
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>

Output:

Question:
How do I style the nested table rows, with the same background color as the parent row?
Bella and Shaun should have the same background color as Ann.
David and Alice should have the same background color as Jim.

Any reason that they are given a background color at all - they could just be see-through and so the color would show through.

It just reads easier if they are colored the same. It groups them together.

I am not querying why you want to do this, I am just asking whether setting the background color of those children to transparent would be good enough.

Oh I see. Let me try that.

I added a rowFormatter to style the childNodes.
If I set the backgroundColor to green, all nested rows are green, as expected.
However, if I set the backgroundColor to 'transparent' or 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', I get the same colors as displayed in my image.

Here is a hack where you use the parent row's index to determine the color.
columns:[
    {title:"Id", field:"id"},
    {title:"Parent", field:"parent"},
    {title:"Children", field:"children",
        formatter:function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
            //create and style holder elements
            let holderEl = document.createElement("div");
            let tableEl = document.createElement("div");
            holderEl.appendChild(tableEl);

            // calculate parent row background color
            let backgroundColor = 'white';
            if (cell.getRow().getPosition(true) % 2 == 0)
            {backgroundColor = 'rgb(239, 239, 239)';}

            let subTable = new Tabulator(tableEl, {
                layout:"fitDataStretch",
                headerVisible:false,
                data:cell.getValue(),
                columns:[
                    {title:"Child", field:"child"},
                    {title:"Age", field:"age"}
                ],

                // set nested row background color
                rowFormatter: function(row){
                    const children = row.getElement().childNodes;
                    children.forEach((child) => {
                        child.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
                    });
                },
            })
            cell.getRow().normalizeHeight();
            return holderEl;
        },
    },
],


Perhaps someone else has a better way, such as getting the parent row's "odd" or "even" class and then use the same class for its nested rows?

As it is a tabulator inside another tabulator, you could just use the tabulator selector twice in your css:
.tabulator .tabulator .tabulator-row .tabulator-cell{
    //some styling here
}

Checkout the Styling Docs for full details on all the CSS classes available

Thank you for the post Oli, but how do you know what color to use for the inner tabulator?
In other words, how do you know if the row in the outer tabulator is odd or even (resulting in white or gray color), so that you can style all the rows of the nested tabulator with the same color?

If you use your dev tools to inspect the table you will see the rows get either a tabulator-row-odd class or tabulator-row-even class depending on their position. Id recommend using your dev tools for all of this, they will provide all the class information you need

Yes I saw that, thank you Oli.
My issue is the following: I create a nested Tabulator inside a cell of the outer Tabulator. While generating the nested Tabulator, I can get the row of the outer Tabulator by using cell.getRow().
However, how do I determine if that row has the tabulator-row-odd class or tabulator-row-even class in the code? At the moment, I just check if the row index is an odd or even number, using getPosition(true) (see my code above). It is working, but still a hack.

Why would you need to do that in the code. Just do it in the CSS no need for JavaScript, the CSS will do that automatically for you no active scripting needed.

If you do for whatever reason need to access the dom element for the row you can call the getElememt function on the row component. Then use standard dome manipulation functions to check classes cell.getRow().getElement().class list.contains("class you are looking for")

Thank you Oli. I will try that. If you want to understand my hack, then copy the code in my first post and replace the columns with the code in my second post. I need to find a better way to get the color of the parent row under "// calculate parent row background color"

I understand what your are saying, and my reply to that is you do not need to use JS at any point to achieve.your results. This is entirely achievable with pure CSS using the info above

Sorry Oli, I don't get it yet. I can see that you target the cell of the nested Tabulator in your code example above. But how do you determine what color to use in your "//some styling here"? It should be the same color as the parent Tabulator's row.
